# iPhone 5 doesn’t connect or show up in iTunes

Tags: macos, iphone

I am using a Dell Inspiron 15 3521.

I replace my iPhone 5 with Apple, and my new phone doesn’t show up or connect in iTunes. It doesn’t even show any device as attached. I’ve reinstalled iTunes three or four times, but I’m still having the same problem. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that you have correctly entered the pin code and
  deactivated the device auto-lock feature
- Do not use a USB hub. Please connect your iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch
  directly to your computer
- Use a different USB port on the PC. For desktops with USB connectors
  on the front and on the back, try with one of the back connectors
- If possible, try using a different USB cable
- Restart the Apple Mobile Device Service and set its Startup type to
  “Automatic” by following [these instructions precisely](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1567)
- Install the iOS drivers required for the PC to correctly recognize
  the device [separately and without installing iTunes](http://www.copytrans.net/support/install-iphone-ipod-touch-and-ipad-drivers-without-installing-itunes/).